# return null while parsing json in loop - android

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception

trying to parse "publisher" key from json object it is returning error but if I parse only "title" key it works fine

```
public ArrayList<BookData> parseJSON(String jsonString){
        try{
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("items");
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject volumeInfo = object.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
               //this title works fine
                String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
               //this publisher is throwing null pointer exception
                String  publisher = volumeInfo.getString("publisher");
                //Log.v("testing title", publisher);
                list.add(new BookData(title, "publisher"));

            }
            return list;

        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        return null;
    }
```

**JSON is here:**

```
"volumeInfo":{  
            "title":"Organic Chemistry",
            "authors":[  
               "Jonathan Clayden",
               "Nick Greeves",
               "Stuart Warren"
            ],
            "publisher":"Oxford University Press"
            }
```

Comment: {"volumeInfo":{  
            "title":"Organic Chemistry",
            "authors":[  
               "Jonathan Clayden",
               "Nick Greeves",
               "Stuart Warren"
            ],
            "publisher":"Oxford University Press"
            }} json should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.add(new BookData(title, "publisher"));` replace this with below given code.

```
list.add(new BookData(title, publisher));
```

Comment: i did this.. still its not working but when i give it in quotes then it works fine

Comment: acutally String  publisher = volumeInfo.getString("publisher");

Comment: this line throwing exception

Comment: @Asad your json is not valid json.

Comment: Your json format should be in the format of  this.{
 "volumeInfo": {
  "title": "Organic Chemistry",
  "authors": [
   "Jonathan Clayden",
   "Nick Greeves",
   "Stuart Warren"
  ],
  "publisher": "Oxford University Press"
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

put a null checker for publisher may be you are getting NullpointerException,hope it ll help you

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getString-java.lang.String-) of `getString` you can see that:

> throws NullPointerException - if the specified name doesn't have any mapping

So if the `title`works fine, that means the `publisher` is not there in your JSON. Check your Json String again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have publisher in quotes when you add it to the array: list.add(new BookData(title, "publisher")) this passes in a string literal, you want to pass in the variable publisher. So simply replace "publisher" in that line with publisher.

Comment: i did this but still its not working but when i give it in quotes then it works fine

Comment: actually String  publisher = volumeInfo.getString("publisher"); 
this line throwing exception